# Review queue stuck at 4 items

Tags: support, review-queues

On the main site my review queue seems to be stuck at 4 reviews, as shown in image. This has been like this for several months now, and I'm wondering what is wrong.

[image]

Are the stuck reviews reviews on my posts, which I don't have access to? Are they reviews I've skipped? What are they, and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see the review count even when you finish all the reviews, is because most of the reviews require more than one user to review that item in order for it to be completed, and the counter on your top bar shows the total number (for everyone). So unless you do the finishing review on an item, it will remain in the counter.

That orange notification shows *everyone* the same number, which is the total amount of reviews. That's why when *you* reviewed, the numbers didn't match up. If you are the final reviewer on a certain item, the total number will drop by one. The notification does not show when there are less than 2 total reviews.

Also see [**Notification for reviews shows way too much**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much)

Comment: Do you see any in the queue? Or is it just me? And if it's just me, then why don't you see them as well?

Comment: No they seem to be gone... First time in quite a few months...

Comment: @holroy .Everyone sees the same number. It is the total number of reviews on the site, so it remains even after one individual has finished reviewing. See my answer..